# Creating a Trigger to update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that would populate a column for the row being updated. Here is what I did, but it's not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PSL_Cases_Address
ON dbo.PSL_Cases
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      IF UPDATE(Permit_No) /*If column not affected skip*/
        BEGIN
            UPDATE psl_cases 
            SET address = (
                SELECT TOP 1 permits.address 
                FROM permits 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PSL_Cases ON PSL_Cases.Permit_No=Permits.PermitsID 
                WHERE PSL_Cases.PSL_CasesID=PSL_CasesID
            ) 
            WHERE dbo.PSL_Cases.PSL_CasesID = PSL_CasesID;
        END
  END;
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: When order by is absent,you will not get desired results..use order by to make it deterministic

Comment: A SQL Server trigger is called ONCE for any update or Insert statement, and the tables _inserted_ and _updated_ are populated for you. This is unlike, for example, Firebird, where the trigger code is called once for each record that was updated or inserted. Your SQL Server trigger code must be crafted to work with the _inserted_ and _updated_ tables.

Comment: @nolaspeaker: the pseudo tables are *Inserted* and *Deleted* - there's no *Updated* ...

Comment: Reference for the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables: [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300(v=sql.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
CREATE TRIGGER PSL_Cases_Address
ON dbo.PSL_Cases
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
 BEGIN
  IF UPDATE(Permit_No) /*If column not affected skip*/
    BEGIN

        UPDATE PSL_Cases

        SET PSL_Cases.[address] = permits.[address] 

        FROM inserted INNER JOIN PSL_Cases ON 

               inserted.[Permit_No] = PSL_Cases.[PermitsID]

         INNER JOIN permits

        ON inserted.[Permit_No] = Permits.[PermitsID]            

    END
END;
```